# R classification tree with Rpart

Tags: r, tree, rpart

I have some data which I would like to segment.
My first thought was classification tree in R from Rpart package.
My training data consists of many explanatory variables and one 0-1 response variable named "sold". The response value "1" appears in about 80% of rows.
When I try to build a tree with `rpart(sold~., training_data, method = "class")`, R is unable to create a tree. I suppose that the reason is that it can't find any segments which differ very much from one another.  After quick inspection of the data, I expect that my tree should look like that left node will have 85% of sold and right node will have 75% of sold.

Is there any way to create a classification tree on such data set?

Comment: How many data do you have in training_data? Please note there is a little typo in method.

Comment: About 70 000 rows and 18 explanatory variables.

Comment: Could you tell what is the error message that R gives you?

Comment: I run: `tree_model = rpart(SOLD~., training_data, method = "class")` and afterward `fancyRpartPlot(tree_model)`. The error that I encounter is then: `Error in apply(model$frame$yval2[, yval2per], 1, function(x) x[1 + x[1]]) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length`

Comment: Does `plot(tree_model)` and then `text(tree_model)` work? Just to see if the error occurs when building your model or when creating your plot.

Comment: Running `plot(tree_model)` results in `Error in plot.rpart(tree_model) : fit is not a tree, just a root`

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.
It seems to be a problem about 'cp'.
Refer to my code:

```
tr1<-rpart(bad~group+amount, data=ra, 
control=rpart.control(minsplit=5, cp=0.001),method='class')
```

When I run this, it worked.
when I increase cp level (e.g. 0.005), it didn't work.